# Radeon VII GPU Not Working

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, gpu, mesa, gpu-driver

I'm having trouble getting a Radeon VII GPU working correctly in Ubuntu. I read that it requires a recent kernel and mesa version. I've installed the latest kernel (5 RC 6) and the latest mesa open source drivers from the Padoka PPA (19.1) but it doesn't look like the GPU is being detected correctly. I am unable to get a signal on my second monitor and the about section of my  settings lists the GPU as

> llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 128 bits)

The xrandr output is below:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
>   minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440 default
>   connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm    2560x1440      0.00*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using kernel 4.20 and adding [these binaries](https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vg20/) to

> /lib/firmware/amdgpu

Source: [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=radeon-vii-linux&num=1)